# How to pass first step response name and user it as second step input in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

How to get first step response name and user it as second step input

1. First step Get country by country code (I input “in”, and I should get country name “India”)
2. I want to user the country name “India” as input country name for the second step 
   How do I do it with groovy?

I try the following code, but it does not work
[image]

```
def def responseCountry = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['GetCountryByCountryCode'].getPropertyValue("Name")

def property = responseCountry.getProperty( "name" )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can modify your groovy as this

```
def gUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = gUtils.getXmlHolder("GetCountryByCountryCode#Response")
def xml = holder.getNodeValue("//*:GetCountryByCountryCodeResult")
def cdataSet = gUtils.getXmlHolder(xml)
def country = cdataSet.getNodeValue("//*:Table//*:name")
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("country", country)
```

and map the testCase property "country" to your the input of next service.

Comment: This does not work as `Table` data is inside the `CDATA`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have separate Groovy Script test step in your test case.

In your case, first parse response and to extract the string which is inside of `CDATA`. Again parse it to get the count name matching the code.

In the first step which is soap request step add a `Script Assertion` with the below code:

```
//Check if there is repose
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'
def lookpcode = context.expand('${#TestCase#CountryCode}')
def dataSet = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).'**'.find{ it.name() == 'GetCountryByCountryCodeResult')} as String
def countryName = new XmlSlurper().parseText(dataSet).'**'.find{ it.name() == 'countrycode' && it == lookpcode)}.parent().name.text()
log.info "Country name is ${countryName} where code is ${lookpcode}"
assert countryName, 'Country name empty or null'
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('COUNTRY_NAME', countryName)
```

In the next step, use property expansion where you needed the country name i.e., `${#TestCase#COUNTRY_NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is added  Property Transfer step to it - it is posted by Helen Kosova

The link is here:

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-get-response-property-value-and-use-it-as-next-step-input/m-p/139502/highlight/false#M23749

Aa regular Property Transfer step

Source (step): GetCountryByCountryCode
Property: Response
Path language: XPath
Expression:
(saxon:parse(//*:GetCountryByCountryCodeResult))//Table[1](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-get-response-property-value-and-use-it-as-next-step-input/m-p/139502/highlight/false#M23749)/name
or just
(saxon:parse(//*:GetCountryByCountryCodeResult))//name
(it seems that saxon picks the 1st matching node by default)